# We need to use several versions of a file in a new project. The file has many branches and labels. How do we manage the file with ClearCase?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

We have a new project that is going to utilize files from an existing project.  The files have many branches and many labels and will be continued to be worked on by the existing.  We want to manage the files the way they are as in we do not want to make copies of the file and would like to keep the files in the same place.

Example: Her are three versions of the same file.

```
File Version 1 - /vob/directory/dbupgrade.sql@@/main/7.1/8
File Version 2 - /vob/directory/dbupgrade.sql@@/main/7.1/7.2/12
File Version 3 - /vob/directory/dbupgrade.sql@@/main/7.1/7.2/7.3/2
```

We will need to use all three of the versions of this file for a release in the new project.

We want to place the file in separate directories like to the following.

```
 - /dbupgradeutility/7.1/dbupgrade.sql@@/main/7.1/8
 - /dbupgradeutility/7.2/dbupgrade.sql@@/main/7.1/7.2/12
 - /dbupgradeutility/7.3/dbupgrade.sql@@/main/7.1/7.2/7.3/2
```

The important thing is to keep it in the vob in one location so the file can be versioned/merged/labeled and used over several releases of the existing project and the new project.

Background - the application has existed for several years.  Right now when a customer (we have many customers) upgrades they have to upgrade one at a time. If they want to go from 7.1 to 7.3 they must upgrade to 7.2 first.  We are trying to build a utility that will upgrade for them.  To do this we will need all three versions (or however many).

We tried symlinks - did not work.
We are thinking about a prebuild script to copy files into a build/tmp directory.

Is there a ClearCase way to handle this?  Are there any other methods we are not thinking about?

Thank you.
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a "ClearCase" native way to support that usecase.

What I have done in the past was to configure one or multiple snapshot views, each one loading the same elements, but for different versions (based on different config spec rules)

And then and I use symlink (not `cleartool ln`, but the regular system symbolic link) to see the second folder view inside the first project view.
That is a workaround, but one which allowed me to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way, but there are complications...

You could use hardlinks to the file element in each of the directories, and then use path specific config spec rules to select each of those versions...

The drawback is that you could not build or test while this file is checked out as checking out ONE would make them all "checked out."

A better way would be to create a script that uses "cleartool get -to..." to transfer the desired version of the script as a view private file in the cariois directories. Which is what you appear to be working on...

From experience,  I would recommend that you make the various upgrade scripts separate elements with differing names, so because it would be FAAARRRRR to wasy to make changes to the wrong scriot if they are all names the same place in the "active development" views...